# How can I adjust my CSS so that Firefox respects the padding when child tag has width: 100%?

Tags: html, css, firefox, width, padding

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    button {
      border-width: 1px;  
      border-style: solid;
      border-color: black;
      -moz-background-clip: padding-box;
      -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
      background-clip: padding-box;
      font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
      font-size: 13px;
      height: 28px;
      padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
      max-width: 180px;
    }
    button > span {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      white-space: nowrap;
    }
    .text {
      max-width: 100%;
      overflow: hidden;
      text-overflow: ellipsis;
      display: inline-block;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<button>
  <span>
    <span class="icon"></span><!-- This will push the text to the right when its shown -->
    <span class="text">Button text that is really, really long</span>
  </span>
</button>
</html>
```

The above code contains a full HTML page that can be copy/pasted into a text editor and rendered in your browser. The issue I have here is that I need the text to fill 100% available width while respecting the padding of 10px on the left and right side. The CSS shown here works for the latest versions of Chrome, Safari and IE. However, in Firefox (versions 7 and 8) the padding isn't being respected.

I understand that if I remove the padding and change the width of the text to 95% it will look similar but I am hoping to avoid that if possible.

Please advise on how this can be adjusted for Firefox and continue to work correctly in the other browsers. Thank you for your time.

Comment: a jsfiddle would be handy if you could

Comment: What is the desired effect you are looking to achieve here. Seems as though you are going about it the wrong way.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not completely sure that this is the best way, but it works:

```
button::-moz-focus-inner {
    padding: 0 10px;
}
```

Your original code: http://jsbin.com/ebinem

With my fix: http://jsbin.com/ebinem/2

Comment: @Boris Zbarsky: Won't the `padding: 0 10px 0 10px;` on `button` then work (as it does in say, Chrome) once `::-moz-focus-inner` is removed?

Comment: No; the behavior observed here has nothing to do with -moz-focus-inner.  See https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=703786